# My order and order details collection query takes too much time suddenly

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, custom-collection, time

I am working on order collection query outside magento directory.It is working fine and also providing results. But suddenly fetching records time is more as compare to previous time. Now it takes more time for fetching same record database. Don't know what happens and what to do?

```
    <?php

$order_collections = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('increment_id')
->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
->addAttributeToFilter('store_id', array('in' => array('finset' => $storeId)));
$order_collections->setOrder('created_at', 'DESC');

foreach($order_collections as $_order)
{ 

    $incrment_id =  $_order->getIncrementId();//die;
    $ordered_items = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($incrment_id);

    if(count($ordered_items)!=0)
    {
        foreach($ordered_items->getAllVisibleItems() as $item)
        {
            $allproductids[] = $item->getProductId();
        }
    }

    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $allproductids));

    $collection->addAttributeToSelect
    (
        array
        (
            'entity_id',
            'name',
            'description',
            'short_description',
            'price',
            'special_price',
            'image_label',
            'small_image_label',
            'thumbnail_label',
            'barcode'
        )
    )->setStoreId($store_id);

    //pr($collection->getData());
                foreach ($collection as $product_details)
                {
                    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
                    $pId = $product_details->getId();
                    $productDetailsImage = $product->load($product_details->getId())->getThumbnail();
                    $loaddata[$product_details->getId()]['bar_code'] = $product_details->getBarcode();
                    $product_image_url = $productDetailsImage;
                    $x = explode('/',$product_image_url);
                    $loaddata[$product_details->getId()]['image_name'] = end($x);

                    if($product_details->getTypeId() == "configurable")
                    {
                        $config = $product_details->getTypeInstance(true);
                        $attribute_details = $config->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product_details);
                        $all_child_product_details = array();
                        foreach($attribute_details as $key=>$attribute_value)
                        {
                            $option_title = $attribute_value['label'];
                            $product_values = $attribute_value['values']; 
                            $op_id = $attribute_value['id'];
                            $code = $attribute_value['attribute_code'];

                            $child_product_details = array();
                            $allChildProductDetails = array();
                            foreach ($product_values as $product_value) 
                            {   
                                $child_product_details = $product_value;
                                $option_type_id = $product_value['value_index']; 
                                $conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($product_details);
                                 $simple_collection = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()
                                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                                ->addAttributeToFilter( $code, array('eq' => $option_type_id))
                                ->addFilterByRequiredOptions();

                                $conf_pro_id = array();
                                foreach($simple_collection as $simple_product)
                                {
                                    $simple_pro =  $simple_product->getData();
                                    if ($simple_pro['is_in_stock'] > 0) 
                                    {
                                        $conf_pro_id[] = $simple_product->getId();
                                    }
                                } 
                                $allChildProductDetails[] = array('new_data'=>$child_product_details,'products'=>$conf_pro_id);
                            }   
                            $all_child_product_details[] = array('type'=>$option_title,'data'=>$allChildProductDetails);
                        }
                        $loaddata[$product_details->getId()]['attribute_details'] = $all_child_product_details;
                    }

                }

    foreach($ordered_items as $item)
    {
        $id = $storeId.$website_id.$_order->getIncrementId().$item->getData()['product_id'];//entityid
        $storeId = $storeId;
        $website_id = $website_id;
        $local_id = '';
        $order_id = $_order->getIncrementId();
        $product_id = $item->getData()['product_id']; //product id
        $parent_product_id = ''; /* Blank this time */
        $product_name = escape_sqlite_value($item->getName());
        $product_sku = escape_sqlite_value($item->getSku());
        $product_barcode = escape_sqlite_value($loaddata[$item->getData()['product_id']]['bar_code']);
        $product_weight = $item->getData()['weight'];
        $product_price = str_replace(',','',$item->getData()['price']);
        $product_quantity = $item->getQtyOrdered();
        $product_type = $item->getData()['product_type'];
        $product_attribute_details = escape_sqlite_value(json_encode($loaddata[$item->getData()['product_id']]['attribute_details']));
        $product_assets_type = 1; /* 1 - Image */
        $product_assets_value = escape_sqlite_value($loaddata[$item->getData()['product_id']]['image_name']);
        $product_tax_amount = '';
        $product_is_discount = '';
        $product_percentage = '';
        $product_discount_amount = '';
        $product_is_gift_wrap = '';
        $product_gift_wrap_qty = '';
        $product_gift_wrap_amount = '';
        $product_item_refunded_qty = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: paste your query too

Comment: Question updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

load product here and skip other product just load product data

```
foreach($ordered_items->getAllVisibleItems() as $item)
        {

          $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());

                    $productDetailsImage = $product->load($product_details->getId())->getThumbnail();
                    $loaddata[$product_details->getId()]['bar_code'] = $product_details->getBarcode();
                    $product_image_url = $productDetailsImage;
                    $x = explode('/',$product_image_url);
                    $loaddata[$product_details->getId()]['image_name'] = end($x);

                    if($product_details->getTypeId() == "configurable")
                    {
                        $config = $product_details->getTypeInstance(true);
                        $attribute_details = $config->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product_details);
                        $all_child_product_details = array();
                        foreach($attribute_details as $key=>$attribute_value)
                        {
                            $option_title = $attribute_value['label'];
                            $product_values = $attribute_value['values']; 
                            $op_id = $attribute_value['id'];
                            $code = $attribute_value['attribute_code'];

                            $child_product_details = array();
                            $allChildProductDetails = array();
                            foreach ($product_values as $product_value) 
                            {   
                                $child_product_details = $product_value;
                                $option_type_id = $product_value['value_index']; 
                                $conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($product_details);
                                 $simple_collection = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()
                                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                                ->addAttributeToFilter( $code, array('eq' => $option_type_id))
                                ->addFilterByRequiredOptions();

                                $conf_pro_id = array();
                                foreach($simple_collection as $simple_product)
                                {
                                    $simple_pro =  $simple_product->getData();
                                    if ($simple_pro['is_in_stock'] > 0) 
                                    {
                                        $conf_pro_id[] = $simple_product->getId();
                                    }
                                } 
                                $allChildProductDetails[] = array('new_data'=>$child_product_details,'products'=>$conf_pro_id);
                            }   
                            $all_child_product_details[] = array('type'=>$option_title,'data'=>$allChildProductDetails);
                        }
                        $loaddata[$product_details->getId()]['attribute_details'] = $all_child_product_details;
                    }
        }
```

Comment: My typo mistake i am using same. Check updated.

Comment: you are using additional query for product and also loading so it will take more time

Comment: If i use this then i am not able to get bar code of product after load it.

Comment: when you load the product it will get all the attribute of the product..

Comment: In edited answer where is "$product_details" variable.

Comment: Replace all with $product variable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32299/discussion-between-mathew-and-qaisar-satti).

Comment: Not able to chat right now. Carry on comments

Comment: It provides me Call to a member function getConfigurableAttributesAsArray() on a non-object after this if($product_details->getTypeId() == "configurable")

Comment: Pass the current object of product

Comment: yes i am passing same like i load             $loadCurrentProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_details->getProductId()); and in configuration if statement i use this                          $attribute_details = $config->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($loadCurrentProduct); and also i use product_details which is coming in foreach loop but same error. Let me know which one i use

Comment: There is no product detail variable in my code use product variable

Comment: yes i change variable no issue for variable.

Comment: foreach($ordered_items->getAllVisibleItems() as $product_details)
 {$loadCurrentProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_details->getProductId()); if($loadCurrentProduct->getTypeId() == "configurable")
                     {
                         $config = $product_details->getTypeInstance(true);
                         $attribute_details = $config->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product_details);}}

Comment: here i am having problem getConfigurableAttributesAsArray(); Here which line of code use.

Comment: This is not product collection  use $product variable.

Comment: $loadcurrentproduct attribute

Comment: i use this but again same error.

Comment: what you want to achieve tell me that you want the configurable option for product?

Comment: Working now correctly.